# display name for reference entity in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I have two entities which are generated from data first approach of entity framework in MVC5.
Following are the Models

```
public partial class Cuisine
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Dish> Dishes { get; set; }
}


public partial class Dish
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int CuisineId { get; set; }

    public virtual Cuisine Cuisine { get; set; }
}
```

When I display the Dishes it is showing as below

[image]

But I want the column names as Name and Cuisine Name instead of Name and Name.
How to do that?
I want to display as **Name** when showing Cuisine list and **Cuisine Name** when showing in Dish list.

Code for my cshtml

```
<table class="table">
<tr>
<th>
    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
</th>
<th>
    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Cuisine.Name)
</th>
<th></th>
</tr>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
<td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
</td>
<td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Cuisine.Name)
</td>
<td>
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.Id }) |
    @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.Id }) |
    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.Id })
</td>
</tr>
}
</table>
```

Comment: Add cshtml code for your table to the question, please.

Comment: Use a view model containing only the 2 properties you want and add a `[Display(Name = "Cuisine Name")]` attribute

Comment: Hi Vadim Martynov, I added cshtml code.

Comment: Just to be clear on my question, if I refer Cusine name field in any other model, I need 'Cusine Name' as my label if it is in the views of 'Cusine' I need 'Name' as my label. Is there any way to do this without duplicating my validations by creating view model?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `DataAnnotation` for this

```
public partial class Cuisine
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name="Name of Cuisine")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Dish> Dishes { get; set; }
}
```

**EDIT:**

You have used `@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Cuisine.Name)` to display the name of Cuisine. You can use `LabelFor()` instead of `DisplayNameFor` to display the name. Change the cshtml and use

```
@Html.LabelFor(model =>  model.Cuisine.Name, "Cuisine Name")
```

Comment: But in my Cuisine view, I want it as 'Name' only and in Dishes view I want it as 'Cuisine Name'. Adding data annotation changes name everywhere

Comment: Hey, thanks for the LabelFor attribute. but I am getting an error when I refer model.Cuisine as in above syntax. It shows that model.Cuisine is not present in the model. I am not getting any error in DisplayNameFor() attribute. It's confusing. Can you explain why this is happening?

Comment: Using `LabelFor()` is not appropriate - it create a `<label>` element which is an accessibility element associated with a form control and there are no form controls. It should be `@Html.DisplayNameFor()`

Answer (score 3):

It would probably be a good idea to use a ViewModel, which aggregates just the properties you need for your view.

```
public class DishVm
{
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Display(Name="Cuisine Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Display(Name="Name")]
        public string DishName { get; set; }
}
```

I don't know how you are retrieving your data, but it would look similar to this:

```
IEnumerable<DishVm> vm = context.Dishes
                                .Include(c => c.Cuisines)
                                .OrderBy(n => n.Name)
                                .Select(x => new DisVm {
                                    Name = x.Cuisine.Name,
                                    DishName = x.Name
                                 });

return View(vm);
```

Your view would then have a new model type: `@model IEnumerable<Yournamespace.Folder.DishVm>`

Comment: But this way I have to duplicate all of my validations. My other fields have several validations. Also, I have a doubt that we loose navigation properties if we create ViewModel(Correct me if I am wrong). Is there any approach other than using ViewModel?

Comment: @aditya, Your not duplicating any validations. A `[Display]` attribute is a view specific attribute and should not be in a data model. Using a view model is the correct approach

Comment: So, If I have 10 other fields and each has some validation like email validation, some regular expression validation in my Model(Dish), should I write all those validations in my view model also? If yes, I am duplicating the work right?

Comment: @aditya, Your view is just display 2 properties. And your not editing anything so no validation attributes would be applied to the view model.

Comment: @stephen Muecke This helps for one scenario. But my worry is I have other views which have the same problem and I have to show 9 columns each using some validation. This is where my worry goes. If I create a view model for every view like this, I may end up creating validations for every view model.

Comment: Every view should have a view model. Its the first thing you should be doing. I don't see what your problem is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103274/discussion-between-aditya-and-stephen-muecke).

Answer (score 0):

On top of your virtual property, decorate it with a [Display(Name="Cuisine"]

Then in your view -> header, drop the .Name in the end. So it says:
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Cuisine)

It's that simple :)